# missing 1 required positional argument error with python connexion app

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a basic rest service in python using Connexion, Marshmallow, and SqlAlchemy. I'm running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
   return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
   response = self.handle_exception(e)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
   return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 68, in wrapper
   response = function(request)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/uri_parsing.py", line 149, in wrapper
   response = function(request)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 196, in wrapper
   response = function(request)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/produces.py", line 41, in wrapper
   response = function(request)
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 120, in wrapper
   return function(**kwargs)
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'applicant'
```

when calling the api like this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8181/myco/app-orchestrator/1.0.0/applicant' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "addressLine1": "123 Street",
  "addressLine2": "unit 2309",
  "birthDate": "01/01/2021",
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
  "firstName": "Test2",
  "lastName": "Tester2",
  "middleName": "T",
  "phoneNumber": "123-321-4321",
  "ssn": "123456789",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip": "12345-1234"
}'
```

I made a git repo with the example code here: https://github.com/thecloudgeek/app_prototype

---- EDIT ------

posted the whole code as I thought it would be helpful.. from a debut perspective, I'm trying to just create an "applicant" with the applicants.create method (`applicants.py line 50`).

the model (`models.py line 47`) has "applicantId" as the primary key but I don't add that into the POST to create an applicant. I wonder if this is causing the issue? My working knowledge is that that the ID would get auto generated and incremented (`db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`)? Do I need to include the `applicantId` in the POST call to create the applicant?

one can also run the app by...
1.) python build_database.py
2.) python server.py

the swagger UI is at: http://localhost:8181/myco/app-orchestrator/1.0.0/ui

------ 2nd EDIT --------

I actually think I'm interpreting the error wrong? I think whats happening is the body of the post call isn't being sent to the `applicants.create` method and thats why its saying that `TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'applicant'` ... so does that mean I have something wrong in my swagger spec?

```
  /applicant:
    post:
      summary: Create applicant
      operationId: applicants.create
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Applicant'
        required: true
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Applicant created
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: Applicant created
        '400':
          description: invalid request
        '500':
          description: error
```

Comment: This is way too much code to analyze/debug on your behalf.

Comment: You have to locate the point where the code is failing and we can help you with that. You are pretending us to analyze, understand and fix your whole application.

Comment: sorry, don't mean for you all to debug it... I added an EDIT section to further describe what I'm seeing

Comment: @lightweight You need to post a [mre]. This is way too much info to expect us to comb through. Surely you could get rid of everything except the minimal amount needed to reproduce the issue. You should also read [ask], which says you shouldn't have to rely on any external links for your question, and to "copy the code into the question itself".

Answer (score 0):

looks like I was missing `x-body-name: applicant` in the `/applicant` swagger spec..

changing to this worked:

```
  /applicant:
    post:
      summary: Create applicant
      operationId: applicants.create
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Applicant'
        required: true
        x-body-name: applicant
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Applicant created
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: Applicant created
        '400':
          description: invalid request
        '500':
          description: error
```